# How to use java stream map inside java stream filter

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 arrays and want to make a list of role.getRoleName() only with elements that are in both arrays using streams.

```
final List<String> roleNames = new ArrayList<>();
roleNames = Arrays.stream(roles).filter(role -> role.getRoleId() 
== Arrays.stream(permissions).map(permission -> permission.getRoleId()));
```

when I write the above code I get

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.util.stream.Stream'

I understand the error, but I don't know the solution of how to make the permissions stream in only permission.getRoleId integers.

Comment: How about using `.equals`? and that too on `roleId`. If `permission.getRoleId` are integers, why do you plan to collect similar data as `List<String>`?

Comment: `roleId` is an int and `roleName` is string. I want to add `roleName` in the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to compare such incompatible types as `int` and `Stream`.

Judging from what you've shown, [`Stream#anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) might a good candidate.

```
roleNames = Arrays.stream(roles)
    .map(Role::getRoleId)
    .filter(id -> Arrays.stream(permissions).map(Role::getRoleId).anyMatch(p -> p.equals(id)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This part `Arrays.stream(permissions).map(Role::getRoleId)` may be pre-calculated and stored into a `Set`.

```
final Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(permissions)
                               .map(Role::getRoleId)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());

roleNames = Arrays.stream(roles)
                  .filter(role -> set.contains(role.getRoleId()))
                  .map(Role::getRoleName)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is collect unique `roleId`s for the array of `Permission`s into a `Set` as a computed result and perform a `contains` check as you iterate through the array of `Role`s. This could be done as :

```
final Set<Integer> uniqueRoleForPermissions = Arrays.stream(permissions)
        .map(Permission::getRoleId)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
final List<String> roleNames = Arrays.stream(roles)
        .filter(role -> uniqueRoleForPermissions.contains(role.getRoleId()))
        .map(Role::getRoleName)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```